# Pass AD user authentication to Azure REST API calls to provision resources

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-authentication, azure-node-sdk

I'm creating a React App that requires authentication into Azure Ad. This is simple enough through the Adal libraries. When a user now requests my app, they are redirected to the login page first to authenticate.

The next step in my app, is for logged in users to be able to create various Azure resources, e.g. VM's through a simple form page in the app. For this, I'm looking at using the **'azure-sdk-for-node'**. My problem, is that users can belong to different subscriptions based on their region globally. There are cases that users are in more then one subscription and have the rights to create resources in whichever subscription they are assigned to.

I'm not sure how to do this with the node SDK, as you only have three methods to authenticate calls:

1. Basic authentication (requires username/password which is redundant because they are already signed in
2. Interactive login (same as above)
3. Service Principal (everone uses the same 'account' to call the REST api's.

Not sure what's the best way then to do this?

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node